# How to modify controls from a different form in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to modify the text in a textbox, or something like that from a different form?

In my program, I need to spawn a new Form2, and have all the textboxes hold information based on stuff entered in Form3. So far I've only done:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.Show();
```

I just don't know how to access form2.textbox1.Text, for example, from form3. I've looked online but didn't find quite what I was looking for, and I've tried a few different things with no success.

Thanks! :)

Comment: You'll need to give form3 a reference to form2 somehow, if you want to modify it from within form3. You could pass it in the constructor, or call an Form3.Update(Form2 formInstance) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are instantiating the Form2 within the code behind of Form3 (calling "new" Form2())...

You can create a public method within Form2 that will provide the accessibility you need. Example:

(within Form2 - code behind)

```
public SetTextboxTextProperty(string text)
{
    this.Textbox1.Text = text;
}
```

From Form3:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.SetTextboxTextProperty("your data");
form2.Show();
```

Comment: This answer worked perfectly, thanks! The other answers were also very helpful, but this was easiest to follow and understand.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the instance of `Form2` into `Form3`:

```
public Form3(Form2 referrer)
{
    var txt = referrer.TextBox1Text;
}
```

and then when calling it:

```
Form3 f3 = new Form3(this);
f3.Show();
```

and you'll just have to make sure that you build a property on `Form2` like this:

```
internal string TextBox1Text { get { return textBox1.Text; } }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the controls defined in each form are not public objects, so you can't access them from outside the form.

Why don't you define a public method in each form to retrieve/set the value you need from the controls you need?

I think that it would be a better approach than exposing your controls.